# Preventing jQuery's Datepicker from changing value of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple button:

```
<input type=button class=datepicker value='Select Date for payroll' />
<input type=button class=datepicker value='Select Date for ?' />
<input type=button class=datepicker value='Select Date for >' />
```

and I have a jQuery's Datepicker attached to it:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

But the default action is to change the text/value of the button when a date is picked. I want to leave the default value. Is this possible?

I have multiple buttons which need to open a datepicker. When the date is selected on the Datepicker, it will fire a function and deal with the value. But I do not want the value choosen to be updated anywhere.
It must be fired on a button click.

Comment: So what the date picker is for?

Comment: Whereelse do you want to store the selected date ?

Comment: OnSelect the datepicker will run some a JavaScript Function and PUT update a field in a database which will be displayed elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [shownOn](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOn)-option of the datepicker-widget:

**jQuery**

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonText: "Select date",
    onSelect: function(dateText){
        alert(dateText + ' selected');
    }
});
```

Note: the parameter of the function of `onSelect` is always of type `string`

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="datepicker" />
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wLtggLnu/)**

**Reference**

[buttonText](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-buttonText)

[datepicker - icon trigger](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger)

[onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect)

Comment: I don't really see how this is relevant? I need it to open when a button is pressed. and NOT update the value of the button anywhere

Comment: @michael it is defintly shown when a button is clicke and the value of the button is not updated in my example ? So I don't understand what you want to achive.

Comment: @michael to fire a function when a date is selected, you can use the `onSelect`-function and do whatever you want with the date.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the input and use the `showOn` attribute

**HTML**:

```
<input style="display:none;" type=button id=datepicker value='Select Date' />
```

**JS**:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonText: "Select date"
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/ogavr7gq/2/

Comment: It needs to be assigned to a button.

Comment: You can hide the input and add the `showOn` attribute

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="datepicker" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonText: "Select date"
});

$("#datepicker").on("change", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("Changed to: " + $(this).val());
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/9oq2wp8j/